# C flat array using matlab syntax

Tags: c, matlab

I'd like to use my own type matrix in C using a syntax matlab-like to access it. Is there a solution using the preprocessor? Thanks. (The following code doesn't work).

```
include <stdio.h>
#define array(i,j) array.p[i*array.nrows+j] //???????????

typedef struct
{
 unsigned int nrows;
 unsigned int ncols;
 float* p;
} matrix;

int main()
{
  unsigned int i=4,j=5;
  float v=154;
  matrix a;

  a.p=(float*) malloc(10*sizeof(float));

  array(i,j)=v;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the matlab syntax requirement?

Comment: `10*sizeof(float)` is not enough to store `4*5` floats.. Moreover `nrows` is not initialized...

Comment: [This can be a solution](http://ideone.com/Et50o7)

Comment: @LPs. Besides some missing parens in the macro, it's nice.

Comment: No need to cast malloc result. And **always** check malloc return value as it could also fail.

Comment: @LPs - Just curious - Why do you not post the code you linked to in your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @ryyker because that code is far from good code, e.g. should test malloc return value.  More over a good answer should warn about indexing and code  obscuration. I have no time now to write a complete answer ;)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry, I'm not getting you about parens...

Comment: @LPs You already addressed this in your earlier comment. `a`, `i`, `j` should be in parentheses in the expanded macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this approach could help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define array(arr,i,j) (arr.p[ i * arr.nrows + j ]) //???????????

typedef struct
{
 unsigned int nrows;
 unsigned int ncols;
 float* p;
} matrix;

int main()
{
  unsigned int i=4,j=5;
  float v=154;
  matrix a;

  a.p=(float*) malloc(10*sizeof(float));

  array(a,i,j)=v;

return 0;
}
```

If you will try to do: a(i,j) it will try to make a call to "a".

Comment: `nrows` and `ncols` are not inited.

Comment: Also, the macro is missing lots of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to pass in the name of your array to the macro, but yes, you could do something like that.

Just as an FYI, MATLAB order is more generally known as "column major". C order is more generally known as "row major order".

I have taken the liberty of correcting 1) your memory allocation and 2) your initialization of the dimensions since they are necessary for the macro to work properly:

```
include <stdio.h>

#define INDEX(mat, i, j) (mat).p[(i) * (mat).nrows + (j)]

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int nrows;
    unsigned int ncols;
    float *p;
} matrix;

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 4, j = 5;
    float v = 154;
    matrix a = {i, j, NULL};

    a.p = malloc(i * j * sizeof(float));
    INDEX(a, i - 1, j - 1) = v;

    return 0;
}
```

Here the order is column major, but the index is still zero-based. I have highlighted this by accessing index `[i - 1, j - 1]` instead of `[i, j]`. If you want one-based indexing to really conform to MATLAB's way of doing things, you can change your macro to this:

```
#define INDEX(mat, i, j) (mat).p[((i) - 1) * (mat).nrows + (j) - 1]
```

Then in `main`, you could do:

```
INDEX(a, i, j) = v;
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help.
I fixed some trivial errors in the initial code. 
I see your answers and I suppose that a matlab syntax cannot be implemented using a generic #define rule in the preprocessor for several structs.
Instead, a #define rule must be written for each specific struct as the following code.

Thank you so much again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define a(i,j) a.p[i*a.nrows+j]

typedef struct
{
 unsigned int nrows;
 unsigned int ncols;
 float* p;
} matrix;

int main()
{
  unsigned int i=4,j=5;
  float v=154;
  matrix a;

  a.nrows=10;
  a.ncols=10;

  a.p=(float *) malloc(100*sizeof(float));

  a(i,j)=v;

  return 0;
}
```